# 400 error with ajax jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I would like to get a second set of eye on this code.

`formPaymentData` is an JSON string of objects extracted from the form. I then went on to form a partial list params from `formPaymentData`, called `_newData`. I used `_newData` for my AJAX request.

the csrfmiddlewaretoken is a `Django` specific term, and I had to include it for the AJAX request. Without it, it produced a `403` error.

All I got was 400 error so I have no clue where to debug...

```
formPaymentData = $form.serializeArray();

console.log('before: -------------------------')
for (var i = 0; i < formPaymentData.length; i++) {
    console.log(formPaymentData[i].name + ': ' + formPaymentData[i].value);
}

var tempArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < formPaymentData.length; i++) {
    if (formPaymentData[i].name == 'products' && formPaymentData[i].value != '') {
        tempArray.push(formPaymentData[i].value);
    }
}
productDataString = tempArray.join(',');
/*Construct JSON OBJECT */

reqParams = ['csrfmiddlewaretoken', 'order_number', 'shop_id'];
var _newData = []; // Extracted data
$.each(formPaymentData, function (index, data) {
    if ($.inArray(data.name, reqParams) !== -1 && data.name != 'products') {
        _newData.push(data);
    }
});

var dataProducts = {};
dataProducts.name = 'products';
dataProducts.value = productDataString;
_newData.push(dataProducts);

reqParams = ['height', 'width', 'length'];
$.each(formPaymentData, function (index, data) {
    if ($.inArray(data.name, reqParams) !== -1 && data.name != 'products') {
        _newData.push(data);
    }
});

JSON.stringify(_newData);
console.log('After stringify:');
console.log(_newData);
/*end Construct JSON OBJECT */

$.ajax({
    url: "/request_label",
    type: "POST",
    data: _newData,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("Request complete.");
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log("failed");
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: try with thios `error(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)` then see what is happening

Answer (score 0):

If your server is expecting JSON, you need to set `contentType: 'application/json'` in your `$.ajax` call; otherwise JQuery will send `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which isn't what the server is expecting. Additionally, you need to call `JSON.stringify` on your `data` so jQuery will send it as is rather than trying to encode it as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: So I am wondering: I currently have `formPaymentData` formed form `.serializeArray()`, so it should be JSON, right? and if I extract and form `_newData` from `formPaymentData`, then `newData` should be JSON too right? (BTW when I went back and made changes to what you suggested, I got a `403` error again)

Comment: You do realize that "JSON" refers to a string-based serialization of an object, not to the object itself? Where's `serializeArray()` coming from?

Comment: `serializeArray()` is a quick way to serialize all inputs from a form into a JSON string, so my data is a JSON string to start with. I actually figured out this problem. All of this code is correct, the only thing was that the server was accepting integers instead of floats.